# Civicrm tutorial for drupal

Tags: drupal

hi i have installed the "CIVICRM" onmy drupal website. but i have no idea how can i manage this. Is anyone have any guideline or any handbook which is useful for understanding the civicrm, Please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best bet is the civicrm book

http://en.flossmanuals.net/CiviCRM/

You can also check the training materials:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/CiviCRM+Training

Comment: Both links are not found

Answer (score 2):

I'd also add that the CiviCRM youtube channel has lots of videos including the CiviCRM 101 Webcast sessions videos and also videos from CiviCON, the annual conference - These range from introductory sessions too more detailed sessions about accounting and finance:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbmFxo3HyO9gaNG40byQjiQ

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the online documentation at:

http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC33/CiviCRM+Documentation

The forums and the IRC channel are also good resources, both the links are available from the CiviCRM home page

lobo